# Get certain line of an out in Python

Tags: python-3.x

My problem is that I don't know how to **get in a variable**, only the line that contains the **SSID** of this out in my Python3 code.
I will be grateful if someone can tell me what to add for get the line of the SSID (SSID: Ramanujan) in the Out, instead of giving me all that data please.

Out:

```
         agrCtlRSSI: -63
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -94
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 130
        maxRate: 130
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 5c:3:39:3d:73:e4
           SSID: Ramanujan
            MCS: 15
        channel: 11
```

And my code is this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport','-I'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
process.wait()
data = ("".join(map(chr, out)))
print(data)
```

Comment: Please describe the problem with your code. What did you expect to happen, what happened instead, and what error messages are shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex:

```
import re

txt = "     agrCtlRSSI: -63\n     agrExtRSSI: 0\n    agrCtlNoise: -94\n    agrExtNoise: 0\n          state: running\n        op mode: station\n      lastTxRate: 130\n        maxRate: 130\nlastAssocStatus: 0\n    802.11 auth: open\n      link auth: wpa2-psk\n          BSSID: 5c:3:39:3d:73:e4\n           SSID: Ramanujan\n            MCS: 15\n        channel: 11"
# print(txt)

x = re.findall(" +SSID:.*", txt)
print(x[0].strip())
```